# Stackoverflow, firefox 3.16.3 cannot post!

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/cant-ask-a-question)

With firefox 3.16.3 Italian I cannot post a new message on www.stackoverflow.com
I get stuck on the page "How to ask", and also if I check  "thanks, I will keep these tips in mind when asking" I cannot see the link to go on.
I have to post with Explorer.

Thanks
Alberto

Comment: Do you have something like NoScript installed on Firefox?

Comment: Even with NoScript installed, this *should* work -- unless you're also disallowing `<NOSCRIPT>` elements in the NoScript settings. Is this the case?

Comment: Closing this as a dupe of a newer question, since the other one has a possible solution.