# Can't ask a question when IE Tracking Protection is enabled

Tags: support, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I am registered on Stack Overflow, and when I click "Ask a question", I get the "make sure you are asking a good question" screen.  At the bottom is the checkbox to tell you I read it.  However, even if I check it, I can't ask any questions.

I do have 100% post capabilities - any idea why I can't ask the questions?

---

Update:

1. I am using IE9 RC, however, I have tried in compatibility mode as well.
2. I don't get the proceed >> link.  I saw that on another post and tried it also.

Comment: What browser are you using? What message are you getting when you try to post? Do you see anything in your browser's JS console?

Comment: Have you clicked the gray "proceed" link?

Comment: Don't close this question; this is actually the first time where the OP followed up and found the reason. So we can keep this around for other people having this issue. Also, this is only partially related to the fact that it's IE9.

Comment: @balpha, [another case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load/184878#184878) where IE 10's tracking protection claimed to have (only) blocked Google Analytics: `SEC7114: A download in this page was blocked by Tracking Protection. http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js`. Still this made SE show *"Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."* Could simply be that IE's message is incomplete, and that IE is actually blocking ALL, like Chad answered...

Answer (score 10):

So, the comment about the JS console make me look at the developers console.  It turns out that the new "Tracking Protection" in IE9 is blocking ALL content from googleapis.com.

That is where stackoverflow gets JQuery from, and therefore JQuery isn't available to make the "proceed >>" Link show up.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if it also does that to Microsoft's CDNs :) Thanks for testing and following up.

Comment: @balhpa, so no `status-bydesign`, I'd say? See also [Stack Overflow freaks out when googleapis.com is blocked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64465/stackoverflow-freaks-out-when-googleapis-com-is-blocked).

Comment: And, @balpha, in [Employer blocks jQuery from Google, DOH!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/employer-blocks-jquery-from-google-doh/23185#23185), someone suggests to use Microsoft's CDN. That *might* be a quick workaround if IE9 is released soon? (Assuming Microsoft won't block itself; I cannot test that though.)

Comment: Couldn't SO just fall back to other CDN when this one is unavailable?

Answer (score 2):

Until IE 9 is released, it isn't supported.  If you are having the same problem in other browsers, please update your question.  Otherwise Stack Overflow policy is to close questions related to unsupported browsers.

Comment: I think it is very poor policy to close questions about browsers you will support in a few weeks.  It could be a problem on your end.  Wouldn't you like to know problems are happening?

Comment: @Chad Beta browsers are in a state of flux, so SO doesn't support them until they've been released. SO keeps these questions around and will review them when the browser is released. @Pollyanna Surely they're [status-declined], not closed.

Comment: @Chad If all the released browsers are working, then the evidence tends to stand against the release candidate.  Note that the release candidate is *NOT* the browser that we'll have to support "in a few weeks".  Further, development time spent supporting unreleased software is development time that is *usually* wasted.  Uptake of new software is slow enough that when it's really released there will be time to fix it before it gains a large following.

Comment: @waiwai933 They could be marked status declined, but they can also be closed as "too localized".  I prefer closing because they are not valid bugs - we're not declining fixing a problem, we're closing a question which is invalid.  But I don't speak for SOIS.

Comment: Personally, I think they should all be `[status-deferred]`, but most of the existing questions are either `[status-declined]` or closed... I guess it doesn't really matter. @waiwai

Comment: Adam, JUST in case you're interested: even in IE10 this (was) [a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load/184878#184878).

Answer (score 2):

Given [another problem report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load/184878#184878), one might see a little blue content filtering icon in the address bar. As a workaround, one can click it and turn off Tracking Protection. That other report also suggests that the erroneous blocking of jQuery might be a (recurring) temporary problem, as it seemed to have been solved when Microsoft fixed the errors in their tracking protection list.

[image: Tracking Protection icon]
<sup>Image [from ZDNet](http://www.zdnet.com/a-tour-of-ie9s-tracking-protection_p5-3040091875/)</sup>