# Dreaded error: "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load"

Tags: support, javascript, internet-explorer, cdn

I'm a huge fan of SO and also a IE user. I cannot use Firefox or Chrome because of company policy. So I get the dreaded error above.

Based on other posts of SO I have tried the following:

- Typing the following in the address bar:
  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js

  Seem like I have complete access.
- Disabling the firewall doesn't help.
- Rebooted my computer, refreshed page, disabled add-ons, no luck.

Also, this is not a temporary outage. I have been having this issue for weeks.

Please do not mark this as duplicate if you are not 100% sure the other post has the solution, as I really need help with this.

Comment: I had the same error. I looked at all posts of finally gave up . I had to use Chrome to fix this.

Comment: `if (SO == IMPORTANT) ie = nil; companyPolicy--; chrome++;`

Comment: What kind of company policy prohibits you from using a civilized web browser?

Comment: Anyway, this *is* a problem, and *should* be fixed. Like, right now.

Comment: @Undo Sadly, many many large archaic corporates to this... who go even further by removing the power/reboot button from a desktop machine - only to be defeated by the wonders of a paperclip!

Comment: @nickhar I'd assume that root access is only dreamed of?

Comment: @Undo: Retarded policy from a retarded company!

Comment: @Undo The privilege of a few certainly in larger orgs, although I find this kind of thing just ridiculous and pretty neolithic.

Comment: @Undo `chrome` would _always_ be increments there

Comment: @Undo Every time someone posts a question on StackOverflow, Chrome becomes more powerful and SE loses money. Congratulations.

Comment: We are using jQuery 1.7.1, not 1.5.2. It is possible that your system admins have configured IE to not fetch cross-domain resources, which may explain what you are seeing. By the way - what version of IE?

Comment: @Oded IE8. Do you know the link that I can examine the cross-domain theory?   Something like http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js ??

Comment: I read somewhere on Internet clearing IE cache could help here. do you know how to clear the cache?

Comment: @JoeTatavaran - Well, if you _can_ see http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js directly, try seeing what is on the network tab of the developer tools when loading a Stack Overflow/Meta page? Is this happening on other sites that use the google CDN? (say [this](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/), for instance)? Does clearing your cache help?

Comment: BTW - IE 8 is no longer supported by us, but at a guess, this would happen to you with newer versions and I don't want to punt this bug as a "version not supported".

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will see if they let me install IE9 or 10 and will try again.

Comment: I use Chrome and I sometimes saw this message also, restarting Chrome usually fixes it.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Joe, using IE10 might (every now and then) get you into trouble that its list of blocked domains has an error, and then blocks all of Google's CDN; see [Can't ask a question when IE Tracking Protection is enabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/cant-ask-a-question-when-ie-tracking-protection-is-enabled). However, at least that can be disabled; just saying that if the problem is solved but comes back, you might want to have a look at that.

Comment: @Arjan - Joe indicated IE8 usage. Joe - can you please check if any of the scripts are blocked, using the developer tools (F12)?

Comment: True, @Oded, but he wrote he was going to upgrade to 9 or 10. (And indeed, Joe, please respond to requests for more details if folks are trying to help!)

Comment: Well, for a large company enforcing the use of IE has some advantages: Auto-Configuration of proxy settings, start page, security policies... I know that there are solutions for Firefox/Chrome too, but they involve extra tools...

Comment: Hmm, for me I get this error in Chrome but in IE it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

My problem is the same, but all the following solutions did not work for me.

I tried the solutions offered in both of these:

- [External JavaScript code failed to load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load)
- ["Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message)

Finally, my problem was solved by changing the DNS (google DNS). Just offer my solution for others who meet the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link.

- [Jquery $.ajax fails in IE on cross domain calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls)

It led me to a solution of sorts.  After reading the linked Microsoft page about "Security: Cross-Domain and Zone Policy", I decided to add the SE link to my trusted sites (Internet Options->Security Tab->Trusted Sites->Sites).  I added https://*.stackexchange.com to the trusted sites and the "dreaded" message went away.

I then added https://stackoverflow.com to the trusted sites.  But IE changed it without my looking to https://*.stackoverflow.com.  This did not get rid of the message.  I went back into Internet Options and deleted the one IE changed and manually typed the right one and added it.  This fixed my problem.

I hope it helps you fix yours.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to those two similar questions:

- ["Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-message)
- [External JavaScript code failed to load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96373/external-javascript-code-failed-to-load)

Just clear the cache and refresh the page: it works now under Chrome on Mac.